# Newbie: Bulkified Task Update trigger replace subject from oppotunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

**Current Setup:** Workflow rules are creating task assigned to a specific opportunity role. A trigger (written by a developer who has left the organization) associates value in business_associate__C picklist to the opportunity team with the specific role. It also limit 1 user to this role on the opportunity team.

**New Business need:** Once the task is created the subject needs to updated with the name in the Business_Associate__C field. Additional the value of the Business_Associate__C picklist on the opportunity needs to be pushed to a matching picklist on the task.

**Since a workflow can not trigger another workflow, a task trigger needs to be created to update the task.**

This is what I have put together so far... Not sure how associate values from related opportunity to the tasksToUpd map for update.

```
Trigger TaskTrigger On Task (after insert)

//Establish variable for whatIDs 
Set <String> whatIDs = new Set<String>();

//Loop New Tasks
For (Task t: Trigger.new) {
whatIDs.put(t.WhatID, t);
}

//List opportunities gathered from Task loop
List <Opportunity> oppty = [Select ID, Business__Associate__C from Opportunity WHERE ID =: whatIDs];

//Create Map for tasks to update 
Map <String, Task> tasksToUpd = new Map <String, Task> ();
For (Task t : Trigger.new) {
tasksToUpd.put(t.whatID, t);
}

//Loop through opportunities, gather 
For (Opportunity o: oppty) {
if (tasksToUpd.containsKey(o.ID)){
***[Get Business_Associate__C Value and Store in TasksToUpd Maps - TasksToUpd.Business_Associate__C]***
***[Get Business_Associate__C Value and Replace last two characters of subject 'BA' and store in TasksToUpd Maps - TasksToUpd.Subject]***
 }
Update TasksToUpd;
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has the right patterns in it but is missing some of the details. I've stripped it down and listed below the code I would write.

Triggers should do as little as possible, so I've added a test to make sure that the trigger only queries when there is one or more Opportunity Id. (Tasks can be added to many objects in a typical org.) Relating the Opportunity to the Task is a matter of putting the right id and object together in a map (`oppsToTasks` in this case). And by moving to a "before" trigger the update of Task can be avoided because the changes made by the trigger will be included when the tasks are inserted.

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
    Map<Id, Task> oppsToTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
    For (Task t: Trigger.new) {
        if (t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
            oppsToTasks.put(t.WhatId, t);
        }
    }
    if (oppsToTasks.size() > 0) {
        for (Opportunity opp : [
                select Id, Business__Associate__C
                from Opportunity
                where Id in :oppsToTasks.keySet()
                ]) {
            Task task = oppsToTasks.get(opp.Id);
            task.Subject = ...
            task.Business__Associate__C = opp.Business__Associate__C;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create a map of opportunity then when you loop on your new tasks you can get the detail of your records from your map. Also you have to call your trigger *before insert* instead of after insert, you don't need to  update your task again.

```
Trigger TaskTrigger On Task (before insert)
{
    //Establish variable for whatIDs 
    Map <ID,Opportunity> whatIDs = new Map<ID,Opportunity>();

    //Loop New Tasks
    For (Task t: Trigger.new) {
        whatIDs.put(t.WhatID, null);
    }

    //get opportunities
    whatIDs = new Map<ID,Opportunity>([Select ID, Business__Associate__c from Opportunity WHERE ID =: whatIDs]);

    //update task subject from oppty
    Map <String, Task> tasksToUpd = new Map <String, Task> ();
    For (Task t : Trigger.new) {
            if (whatIDs.get(t.WhatID) != null){
                    t.Subject = whatIDs.get(t.WhatID).Business__Associate__c;
            } 
     }
 }
```